In "A Gest of Robyn Hode" what is the significance of the word "gode"?
A Gest of Robyn Hode is one of the earliest surviving texts featuring a tale about the Robin Hood character.
Consider the following excerpt of the text...

loke ye do no husband harm
That tilleth with his plow
No more ye shall no gode yeman
That walketh by gren-wode shawe;
Nor no knight nor no squire
That wol be a gode fella.


What contemporary word is best related to the archaic word "gode" ...



Number
Word
Definition




1
god
nounAn omnipotent, omniscient, ethically good being who is worshipped (as in Judaism, Christianity, Islam, and Hinduism) as creator of the universe


2
good
adjectivepleasure inducing for a specific individual person, but not pleasurable for society in generale.g. "This is a good tasting sandwich"


3
good
adjectiveethical, moral, and/or self-sacrificing, especially while improving the welfare of a group of people"Boiled unground wheat, not noodles, and not bread, is good in that less carbon dioxide is emitted in the case where whole wheat is used."


4
guard
protect or secure


5
goad
taunt or tease




Suppose that we were to translate the following sentence from 17th century English into contemporary English. What might the result be?

"No more ye shall no gode yeman"


Note that the phrase, "No more ye shall" is equivalent to one or more of the following phrases...


No more shall you
No more will you
You shall not
You will not
Know more you shall
You shall know and learn more



We have somthing like this...


"You will not no gode yeman"


... or this...


"You shall not no gode yeman"


Do you suppose that it is all one imperative command, or two seperate imperative commands?We can split the original line into two seperate lines.You shall not do these things anymore!No gode yeman!...or differently...No more ye shall!And more than that, no gode yeman!The string of text "no gode yeman" is now a separate imperative command.

"know" versus "no"
The words "know" and "no" have the same sound, but different spellings.

You shall not know god yeman
No more ye shall know gode yeman


Some candidate translations and commentaries are shown below. However, at least one of the proposed translations is in-consistent in meaning with the original text. Which translation do you believe best represents the original text?


No more shall you goad young mendo not taunt young menyou shall not gode yemanNo more ye shall no gode yeman

No more you shall no guard yemanno more shall you fail to guard the yemanan imperative command to guard the yeman in the futureNo more ye shall no gode yeman

in scolding toneas a reprimandNo more shall you do these things, you no good yeman!(you are a no good yeman!)No more ye shall! You no gode yemanNo more shall you do these things, you no good yeman!(you are a no good yeman!)No more ye shall no gode yeman

You shall not know god yemanNo more shall you know god young manNo more ye shall no/know gode yeman

Know more; You shall know god youngmanNo more ye shall no gode yeman(an imperative command to learn more)




I read it as meaning 3, with it continuing from the first term, saying that you will not harm the plowing husband, the good yeoman, the squire, or the knight.

Is there anything I can do to improve my answer for you?

I think that it is meaning 3. The stanza is saying that you will not harm the plowing husbandman, the good yeoman walking in the wood, the knight, or the squire (levels of citizenship in English society). You can see a similar phrase in lines 3 and 4:

I shall you tel of a gode yeman,
His name was Robyn Hode.

So basically, the stanza is saying

Look, do no husbandman harm
That tilleth with his plow
Neither should you [harm] a good yeoman
That walks within the woods
Nor [harm] no knight nor no squire
That is a good person.

These lines are in response to Little John asking him who they should rob, beat, and bind, with further lines afterwards where Robin says that they will rob, beat, and bind the (corrupt) bishops and the Sheriff of Nottingham.

'Maistar,' than sayde Lytil Johnn,
'And we our borde shal sprede,
Tell vs wheder that we shal go,
And what life that we shall lede.
'Where we shall take, where we shall leue,
Where we shall abide behynde;
Where we shall robbe, where we shal reue,
Where we shal bete and bynde.'
'Therof no force,' than sayde Robyn;
'We shall do well inowe;
But loke ye do no husbonde harme,
That tilleth with his ploughe.
'No more ye shall no gode yeman
That walketh by gren -wode shawe;
Ne no knyght ne no squyer
That wol be a gode felawe.
'These bisshoppes and these archebishoppes,
Ye shall them bete and bynde;
The hy sherif of Notyingham,
Hym holde ye in your mynde.'


Husbandman, surely?

@KateBunting I will edit that in. Thank you. :) My Middle English is very much a dabbling thing.

Mine is nonexistent, but the guy is obviously a farmer!
